# SQL where to put condition statement in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and a SQL query like this

```
UPDATE table2 SET param = (SELECT param1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.name = table2.name AND table1.date=table2.date)
```

I want to add another condition, so table2 updates column "param" only, where param is 1 (or 2,3...

I tried the following but got an error

```
UPDATE table2 SET param = (SELECT param1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.name = table2.name AND table1.date=table2.date) AND param='1'
```

Comment: `AND param='1'` should be `WHERE  param='1'`

Comment: i get error #1242 when i do this
UPDATE table2 SET param = (SELECT param1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.name = table2.name AND table1.date=table2.date) WHERE param='1'

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UPDATE table2 SET param = (SELECT param1 
FROM table1 WHERE table1.name = table2.name AND table1.date=table2.date) WHERE param='1'
```

Comment: i tried this one but it return error: SQL error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @Martin Kuchen: Then your original update statement is already incorrect. nguyenpt only shows you how to add a restriction here. But if your statement is wrong, it stays wrong of course. Obviously there can be more than one row per name and date in table1, so which of these do you want to use for the update? I suggest you add table descriptions to your request and think about how to determine which rows to pick from table1.

Comment: @MartinKuchen SQL error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row means the value you set into param more than one. Please change the query inside () statement.
If you don't need change any logic, you can try add "AND table1.date=table2.date limit 1"

Comment: @nguyenpt: On a side note: Next time please don't write code-only answers (and I consider "try this" code-only). Instead explain what you are doing dfferently (e.g. "You added `AND` to the `SET` clause where it doesn't belong. The `UPDATE` statement needs a `WHERE` cause instead where you state your criteria.")